# The ratio of Hankel functions

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

I have to obtain an asymptotic solution for small real positive $x$ for the ratio of Spherical Hankel functions ($n=0,1,2....)$

${h^{(2)}_n(x)}/{h^{(1)}_n(x)}$

I found that series should be

$-1 + i C_n x^{2n+1}+O(x^{2n+2})$

but how can I get the accurate coefficient at least for the first non-zero order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{h^{(2)}_n(x)}{h^{(1)}_n(x)}=-1+\frac{i \pi  x^{2n+1}}{2^{2n}\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}+{\cal O}(x^{2n+2}).$$
For $n\geq 1$ the next term is actually of order $x^{2n+3}$.

Comment: Can you explain please how you got it?

Comment: Wikipedia has the [power series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Hankel_functions:_h(1)n,_h(2)n) of $h^{(1)}_n$, and $h^{(2)}_n$ is the complex conjugate of $h^{(1)}_n$.